# Can we use Blackberry as GSM modem?

Tags: blackberry, modem, gsm

Can I use the **Blackberry** as a **GSM modem** from an application running on the blackberry itself?

I know it's possible to use the blackberry as a **GSM modem** from a PC.

Comment: I don't get why you would want to do this. Just open a socket or http connection to the service your application needs to communicate with. If you want to use the same data path as you would tethered, specify deviceSide=true and the APN settings.

Comment: Perhaps he wants to call a modem on the other end?

Comment: yes I want to make a call to a device on the other end and transfer series of packets of data.

Comment: A "GSM modem" isn't really ad Modem in that it doesn't modulate data onto an analog signal. It is a misnomer arising from that fact that it behaves like a modem from the point of view of a computer connected by a serial port (or a pseudo serial port on a USB connection). That allows the computer to use existing interface software to establish a PPP connection to the Internet using the wireless carrier's APN.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, application that running on the blackberry itself will use automatically the internet access. In this case it would not need to set the blackberry to be an GSM modem.

Meanwhile, I guess that this question would be better to be asked in SuperUser.